# How can I read file names from a folder and store them into a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to make a website and all I want is to have an array in my javascript file that has the names of every file in my "images/" folder.

I've tried everything. I've scoured stackoverflow over and over again and nothing has worked. I've tried ajax and php functions, and I've tried using MAMP and XAMPP as my local web server (I'm on mac, by the way, in case that's important). Whenever I try to load images and just log the file name to the console, nothing happens. I have no idea what to do.

I'm fairly certain the problem is that access to my directories is blocked, and it's the local web server that's not working, not the code (though I could be wrong).

Here are some more specific examples of solutions I've tried that haven't worked:

**Attempt 1**
index.php:

```
...
<?php
    $images = array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')));
    $imagesJS = json_encode($images);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images =  "<?= $imagesJS ?>";
</script>
</script src="js/bodyScript"></script>
...
```

bodyScript.js:

```
console.log(images); // returns null on attempt
```

**Attempt 2**
bodyScript.js:

```
var folder = "images/";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                images.push(val); // add file name to array (doesn't work)
                console.log(val); // log to console for debugging purposes (also doesn't work)
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

**Attempt 3**
bodyScript.js:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "images/",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("td > a").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr("href")); // nothing gets logged
     });
  }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Is the images folder on the client (your computer) or the server?

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "http://mysite/getdirectories.php",
  success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

PHP (getdirectories.php)

```
$images = array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')));
exit(json_encode($images))
```